# Python form-data throwing error - working in Postman

Tags: python, file, python-requests, form-data

I am trying to make a post call for uploading an excelx document to a given endpoint. Here is how my postman looks

Here's the profile key value:

```
{
  "warnings_for_required_and_disabled_fields": true,
  "keep_locked": false,
   "doc_profile": {
      "name": "XLSX Upload",
      "type": "EXCELX"
    }
}
```

and here are all of the relevant headers in my postman:

The code I tried writing myself:

```
def UploadDocument():
 url = "example.url"

payload="{\"profile\":{\"warnings_for_required_and_disabled_fields\":true,\"keep_locked\":false,\"doc_profile\":{\"name\":\"XLSXUpload\",\"type\":\"EXCELX\"}}}"
files={
    "file": ('example.xlsx', open(r'C:\example\example\example.xlsx','rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', None)
}

headers = {
    'X-Auth-Token': 'SomeToken',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.loads(payload), files=files)
print(response.text)
```

The exception I am getting back is:

```
{"error":{"code":"NRC_FAILURE","code_message":"Operation Failed",""detailed_error_message":"The server encountered an internal erro r and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is orverloaded or there is an error in the application.","dms_version"0:"10.4.5.593","function":"handle_exception"}}
```

What I have currently tried is:

1. I copy pasted the Postman generated code for python, that didn't work
2. I thought that maybe the json wasn't getting loaded correctly, so I tried to stringify it.
3. I tried python requests's "json" parameter, that didn't work

This is how my postman set up looks like:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNVnC.png](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c38D.png](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have tried everything from including different headers, loading the profile key directly from a json file, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting content-type in headers:

```py
import requests


def upload_document():
    url = "example.url"
    payload = {
        "profile": {
            "warnings_for_required_and_disabled_fields": True,
            "keep_locked": False,
            "doc_profile": {
                "name": "XLSXUpload",
                "type": "EXCELX"
            }
        }
    }
    files = {
        "file": ('example.xlsx', open(r'C:\example\example\example.xlsx', 'rb'),
                 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', None)
    }  # is the file name here and in JSON above correct?
    headers = {
        'X-Auth-Token': 'SomeToken',
        # no other headers here, they will be set automatically
    }
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        headers=headers,
        json=payload,
        files=files,
    )
    print(response.json())
```

And take a look at other headers in postman, maybe there's something missing.